# Real valued function generalizes to functions on $f:[a,b] \to V$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $V$ be a complete normed vector space.

Prove that if $f:[a,b]\to V$ is continuous then $||\int^b_af(x)d(x)||\le \int^b_a||f(x)||d(x).$

Definition: Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ $a<b$ and let $f$ be a real valued function on $[a,b]$. We say that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if there exists a number $A\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|S-A|<\epsilon$ whenever $S$ is Riemann sum for $f$ corresponding to any partition of $[a,b]$ of width less that $\delta$.

Comment: What IS the definition they give for real valued functions?

Comment: @IgorRivin I am not sure what you mean by the definition of real valued function? Real valued function is a function whose values are real numbers.

Comment: Not of the real valued function, but of the integral thereof.

Comment: We have no idea what kind of integral you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If $f: [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous, then so are
$$
f_+=\max\{f,0\} \quad\text{and}\quad f_-=\min\{-f,0\},
$$
and 
$$
f=f_+-f_- \quad\text{while}\quad |f|=f_++f_-.
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\Big|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\Big|&=\Big|\int_a^b (f_+(x)-f_-(x))\,dx\Big|\le
\Big|\int_a^b f_+(x)\,dx\Big|+\Big|\int_a^b f_-(x)\,dx\Big| \\
&=\int_a^b f_+(x)\,dx+\int_a^b f_-(x)\,dx=\int_a^b (f_+(x)+f_-(x))\,dx=\int_a^b|f(x)|\,dx
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! So proving for $f:[a,b]\to V$ is similar to proving for $\mathbb{R}$?